# Windows 7 IIS problem

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5

the thing is that I just installed IIS in my Windows 7 computer to test it out, but I'm getting this error as soon as I try to load the localhost on my web browser:

Service Unavailable

---

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I found [this solution](http://foxsys.blogspot.com/2009/08/iis7-service-unavailable-http-error-503.html) but it didn't work. Anyone has an idea of what's going on?

Thanks!

More Info:

I checked on the Application Pools, as soon as I go to http://localhost/ it stops the application pool of thw website I try.

Comment: What's the error in the application log?

Comment: How can I see this? I thought in the event viewer but seems like no...

Comment: I think this is what you asked:

The worker process for application pool 'DefaultAppPool' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config', line number '0'.  The data field contains the error code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed it!

mrdenny thanks for pointing the log out. With that I was able to search on google in a more specific way. My problem was this:

"The worker process for application pool 'DefaultAppPool' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
' trying to read global module configuration data from file '\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config', line number '0'. Worker process startup aborted."

Solution:

To fix this issue, give the IIS_IUSRS account explicit read rights on the 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config' file, do a iisreset and you should be fine.

[Source](http://darkcsharp.blogspot.com/2008_05_01_archive.html)

Comment: In my case, the password had changed for the app pool identity...

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and the previous answer did  not solve.

This following solved it:
Give permission to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` folder to `Network Service` user.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I was having the same problem with the  'Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions' error.  I tried your solution, but you have a typo.  Its IIS_IUSRS not ISS_IUSRS.

Regardless, I use another approach, which is to run the IIS Server as yourself instead of IIS_IUSRS.  This is not as secure, but here's how to do it anyway:
1. highlight your Default Web Site, or virtual directory
2. Click on Basic Settings in Actions pane
3. Click "Connect As" button
4. Choose "specific user", then click set and type in your user name and password